# Skype Bots - Please tell me I'm missing something

Tags: botframework, bots, telegram, skype

Working on an application and developing chat integration bot. Note that contrary to some news bots or other tools, there is no central website or server that the bot gets its data from. The software installation comes with a repository, and that is where the bot connects to. Thus, every user, upon installing the software, will basically get their own copy of the bot, alongside with their own repository, etc.

Now, having done that for Telegram: You open the telegram client, initiate a chat with the botfather, get the token for your new bot with one or two commands, and then add that token to my application. Done. Easy for the user to follow, takes a few minutes at most and they have a working bot.

Trying to do the same with Skype, the users must:

1. Sign up for an Azure account
2. Provide credit card and phone number verification (that's probably where some users will stop right away)
3. Log on to the Azure Portal
4. Create a bot channel, through a myriad of different screens I have to guide the user through.
5. Have the user obtain the bot's password, again through a variety of different screens he needs to be guided through. (if the user hasn't given up yet, at this point he'll definitely get grumpy)
6. Enable the Skype channel, and enable the bot to be added to group chats.
7. Attempt to locate the bot via Skype and eventually add it in.

Now, if I wanted to document this properly, this will be a 10-15 page document with tons of screenshots and all. To do what Telegram does in two minutes or even less. There's so many opportunities in all of this for something to go wrong, that I can't even consider forcing my users to go through this.

Surely, I must be missing something? It can't be that you have to go through this horrible mess of an over-engineering spectacle that is second to none, just to get the most basic bot to function?

All I need is a means to say "this is the bots name, give me its token and API URL so that it can send messages using the REST API". But I can't seem to find this for Skype.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's Bot Framework?

Comment: Yes - from what I've found that's the only way?

Comment: Are you using the bot framework with your telegram bots?

Comment: I am not sure what you guys mean with the "bot framework". The application runs in Oracle databases, and is written in PL/SQL. It's not dot net.

Comment: The question here is not clear. What are you asking exactly?   

Yes, configuring a bot on Skype involves more steps than configuring a bot on telegram.  Have you setup a Facebook bot?  It is even more complex, and involves even more steps.  Telegram, Skype, and Facebook are all different products.  Isn't it amazing that you can create one bot, and deploy it to these multiple disparate channels using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: I think you answered the question already Erik. And no, in my case using the bot framework to deploy it to those other channels isn't applicable. What I'm looking to do is ship a product that can quickly and easily be integrated through a bot into whatever chat platform it is that the user's team uses. Key being quickly and easily (by the user himself). It looks like Skype isn't going to be on that list then.